# How to remove values from database that doesn't have a certain value

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, wcf

The title above is the best way I could try the ask the question, so sorry if it isn't titled correctly after what you read about the question below. :)

So, iv'e got coding below where I add data to certain columns in my data table from information that I get from another table. It's almost like a VLOOKUP in Excel.

```
    var qisg = new QuoteItemSectionGroup
    {
        SectionGroup = db.SectionGroups.Where(x => x.Name == "Ali Bottom Rail" && x.Section == TruckSection.FrontEndRequirments).First(),
        //StockItem is set here
        StockItem = quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Royal Corrugated" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Royal Smooth Riveted" ? db.StockItems.Where(x => x.StockCode == "AEX165").First() : null,
    };
    qisg.Quantity = qisg.StockItem == null ? 0 : 1;
    qisg.Weight = Math.Round(((double)qisg.Length * (double)qisg.Quantity) * (double)qisg.StockItem.Mass, 2);
    qisg.Cost = Math.Round(((double)qisg.Length * (double)qisg.Quantity) * (double)qisg.StockItem.UnitCost, 2);
    quoteItem.SectionGroups.Add(qisg);
```

As you can see where I set my `StockItem`, I say: **if** the `BodyType` = `Royal Corrugated` then the `StockItem` code should be `AEX165` **else** the stock code should be `null`. I get **all** the information that I need for the *Quantity, Weight and Cost* from the **StockCode** just like VLOOKUP.

Now my big issue is that, when I set the **else** to *null* in my `StockItem` I won't be able to get any information from my datatable, except the `SectionGroup` as I set it manually. So when the StockItem is null I want to be able to skip the whole `var qisg` and not add the data to my data table.

If I can't skip the `var qisg` it throws me the following error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

In the coding below:

```
    foreach (var sectionGroup in quote.Items.First().SectionGroups)
        bills.Add(new ListOfBills
        {
            Cost = sectionGroup.Cost,
            PricePerMeter = sectionGroup.Price_m,
            GroupName = sectionGroup.SectionGroup.Name,
            Length = sectionGroup.Length,
            Quantity = sectionGroup.Quantity,
            StockCode = sectionGroup.StockItem.StockCode,
            StockDescription = sectionGroup.StockItem.Description,
            TruckSection = sectionGroup.SectionGroup.Section,
            Weight = sectionGroup.Weight,
            Width = sectionGroup.Width
        });
    return bills;
```

So I really need to know how to skip the variable if the `StockItem` is *null*. Any help or advice would really be great! And sorry that I do not know all the correct technical terms for some of the objects and types is c#, so please just look past it and if you need any more information, please don't hesitate to ask. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want add new **qisg** to the sectionGroup only if **StockItem** is not null. Try to change your code as below:

```
var stockItem = quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Royal Corrugated" || 
                quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Royal Smooth Riveted" 
                    ? db.StockItems.Where(x => x.StockCode == "AEX165").First() 
                    : null;

if(stockItem != null)
{
   var qisg = new QuoteItemSectionGroup
   {
      SectionGroup = db.SectionGroups.Where(x => x.Name == "Ali Bottom Rail" && x.Section == TruckSection.FrontEndRequirments).First(),
      StockItem = stockItem,
   };

   qisg.Quantity = 1;
   qisg.Weight = Math.Round(((double)qisg.Length * (double)qisg.Quantity) * (double)qisg.StockItem.Mass, 2);
   qisg.Cost = Math.Round(((double)qisg.Length * (double)qisg.Quantity) * (double)qisg.StockItem.UnitCost, 2);

   quoteItem.SectionGroups.Add(qisg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I don't understand your problem.
It seems you just have to decompose the treatment.

```
var myStockItem = quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Royal Corrugated" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Royal Smooth Riveted" ? db.StockItems.Where(x => x.StockCode == "AEX165").First() : null;

if(myStockItem != null)
{
    var qisg = new QuoteItemSectionGroup
    {
        SectionGroup = db.SectionGroups.Where(x => x.Name == "Ali Bottom Rail" && x.Section == TruckSection.FrontEndRequirments).First(),
        //StockItem is set here
        StockItem = myStockItem,
    };
    qisg.Quantity = qisg.StockItem == null ? 0 : 1;
    qisg.Weight = Math.Round(((double)qisg.Length * (double)qisg.Quantity) * (double)qisg.StockItem.Mass, 2);
    qisg.Cost = Math.Round(((double)qisg.Length * (double)qisg.Quantity) * (double)qisg.StockItem.UnitCost, 2);
    quoteItem.SectionGroups.Add(qisg);
}
```

Is it what you need...?